# In EmEditor, how to normalize multiple consecutive whitespaces to 1 in multi-column file

Tags: emeditor

When I search for \s\s+ to replace with “ “, lines in column 1 and 2 get concatenated, unless text line in column 1 ends in punctuation mark. Please provide expression to normalize whitespaces w/o losing multi-column data structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the file is `TAB`-separated, and `\s` includes `TAB`s. If you are interested in only spaces, please use   `+` or  `{2,}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Yutaka. But this expression finds all the text, none of the white spaces. I still need to find 2 or more consecutive whitespaces to remove them with one.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer.

Comment: “ {2,}” works well.  Thanks!!